# reduce on new Array not executing correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I need to execute a reduce function not on members of an array but rather just on the indices. I tried the following:

```
const len = 4;
const arr = new Array(len);
const total = arr.reduce((accum, dummy, index) => calculate(accum, index), 0);
```

This doesn't work. I tried adding some printouts and it seems that the function in the reduce statement never gets called.

If however I replace arr with:

```
const arr = [0,1,2,3];
```

then it works fine. What am I missing? The length of the array as I use it is indeed verified to be 4, so why isn't it executing the function 4 times as it should?

Comment: `reduce` function when called on an empty array returns the initial value. If you don't pass the initial value to reduce function and call reduce on an empty array, you will get a `TypeError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Array(len)` creates an array with a `length` property of `len`, but *without* any array index own-properties:

```js
const arr = new Array(3);
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty(1));
```

This is called a *sparse array*, and should almost always be avoided because creating them produces odd results like you're experiencing. You can `.fill` the array first so that each array index value from 0 to the `length - 1` of the array is assigned a value:

```js
const arr = new Array(3).fill(0);
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty(1));
```

Then the `reduce` will be able to iterate over the array.

As the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) says:

```
9. Repeat, while k < len,
  a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
  b. Let kPresent be ? HasProperty(O, Pk).
  c. ****If kPresent is true, then*****
    i. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
    ii. Set accumulator to ? `Call(callbackfn, undefined, « accumulator,   d. kValue, k, O »)`.
```

Since a spare array does *not* have any array index own-properties, the `.reduce` callback (named `calllbackfn` in the spec) is never called.

Comment: Hello sir Wait for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889456/create-schema-using-an-object#61889456